# Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException is found during my JMeter test

Tags: jmeter, httprequest

OS: Windows7 64-bit
JMeter version: apache-jmeter-2.11

HTTP Request configuration is as follows:
Protocol: http
Method: GET
Follow Redirects and Use KeepAlive are checked

During execution there was found the following exception against the above HTTP Request:

```
responseCode: Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException
responseMessage: Non HTTP response message: my-url.com
```

Comment: Add a new HTTP Request sampler, and only change the 'server name or IP' value to google.com or equally plausible known host.  Other settings are defaults, you do not need to change.
Click run. 
If you get an error, you have an installation/configuration issue, we need more information to resolve. Check jmeter.log for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connected to the internet / network / VPN etc. Are sure that you are able to access the via your Browser?  The exception is clearly saying the It could not find the server you are trying to access.

Comment: Internet connection was available, I think. It is accessible via browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and found that I was using wrong server host URL.
Instead of using just server host, I had also added filer path to it.

For ex is your API end point is -

```
https://auth.test.com/am/oauth2/access_token?realm=employees
```

then you should use only following as "Server Name or IP"

```
auth.test.com
```

You should mark protocol field as https for https request and rest of the URL should be entered Path field, that is -

```
/am/oauth2/access_token?realm=employees
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if there are any firewall or proxy requirements. To check this try to ping and trace the domain name from the CMD.

Eg: `ping example.com` and `tracert example.com`

Also, if required add the DNS with the corresponding ip address to the windows host file(C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts).
Eg: open the host file in admin mode then add an entry in the new line with ip address followed by domain name like

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the domain that you are calling is having the right TLS version. By default, chrome calls TLS 2.

Just start the jmeter with following parameters -Djavax.net.debug=all to see what version of handshaking is happening.